# CV template stopped working after updating package

Tags: luatex, templates, cv

I recently updated all my packages since it had been a while. I noticed that my CV now produces errors when compiling (I am using LuaLaTeX). The same file compiled just fine right before the updates. My problem is that I am not finding any of these errors on the web, and so I am completely lost on how to fix them. I should mention that the last error says I am missing the verbatim package, but I find no such package to download in the MikTeX console.

The template I am using is AltaCV: https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV. I downloaded the template again and tried to compile the sample, and it shows me the same errors. I fear that the template might have become incompatible, but I am still hoping for a fix. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: After looking around, it seems as though I have to run the snippet `fmtutil-user --all` somewhere. But I do not know where or how. I am quite lost and any indication in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: pdfx is currently broken, it uses internally a package which is not compatible with a new latex. The author knows about the problem but I don't know when he will update pdfx, you could ask him.

Comment: and miktex users don't have to call `fmtutil-user --all`, that is a texlive command.

Comment: I see, that doesn't sound too good. However, even though I'm a MikTeX user, I get the error message `C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3backend\l3backend-luatex.def:44: LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected. [  }]` when compiling other documents as well. Is there a way to fix this? (For other projects this is the only error I get...)

Comment: you probably didn't update all files, check for updates in the console in user *and* admin mode.  And regarding the template: you can probably simply remove the usepackage{pdfx} line and look what happens.

Comment: Okay, I tried looking for updates as admin and didn't find any new ones, however for some reason the things are working now. I also commented out the line that requires pdfx in the CV template, and it compiles it just fine again. So everything seems to be solved. Thank you very much for your help!